# Geometric effect with js/css

Tags: javascript, css, effect

i discovered this effect (http://prntscr.com/1dgvz9) in this website (http://builtbybuffalo.com/). Do you know a javascript plugin or css tip for this effect ?

Thank's !

Comment: Here's a [tutorial](http://jtauber.github.io/articles/css-hexagon.html) for achieving the effect using CSS3.

Comment: yes i spoke about the shape of images. If you look the source code, it's not built like this. It's a layer with javascript i think.

Comment: @VimalStan This tutorial only shows how to do CSS shapes with solid color backgrounds.  The article is very useful though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tutorial will take you through this step by step:

> http://www.queness.com/post/13901/create-beautiful-hexagon-shapes-with-pure-css3

Edit:

This tutorial implements hexagons (with image backgrounds) using pure CSS much as the example website you gave.